independent events in the sameprobability space
When throwing a die, let event $A$ be $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and event $B$ be $B=\{1,4\}$, so the intersection being $A \cap B=\{1\}$.
By definition of independent events, $A$ and $B$ are independent. I don't see the independency by intuition. How to understand this?
Thanks a bunch!!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please, use MathJax notation when posting a question. I'll edit it for you this time, please, conform to the site's COC.

I believe this question and answers to it could be helpful : Independence of two events with non empty intersection. The answer by @antkam  addresses your question, at least in the way I would like to answer it.

I think I see your concern - the word independent intuitively does not always seem to agree with the probability definition.
This happens. Sometimes you just need to look at the problem slightly differently:
If $Pr(A|B)=Pr(A)$ then events $A$ and $B$ are independent. This, I think, is easy to see intuitively - event $B$ is not affecting $Pr(A)$.
In this case, $Pr(A|B)=\frac{1}{2}$ because the sample space is reduced to $\{1,4\}$ and only one of these two outcomes is part of event $A$.
Since $Pr(A)=\frac{1}{2}$, we have $Pr(A|B)=Pr(A)$ and hence $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

RedFive: Your explanation is fine but it may be easier to look at it from the other way and say that P(B | A) = 1 !!!!!! so they are definitely not independent events.

$P(B|A)=\frac{1}{3}$ so yes, they are.

that's right. my mistake. a very bad example indeed !!!!

I see.So $A$ and $B$ being independent means if you reduce the sample space to one of them, the probability does not change.
Further, in finite classical model, $A$ and $B$ being independent means sample points in $A$
is taken from $B$ and $B^c$ proportionally. Is that correct?

The first part, yes. The second part... I'm not entirely sure what you mean.
